# Inline formsets - How to set default values for child form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, inline-formset

I have an inline formset factory with a Parent entity and a child entiy.

I need to set the **child form** initial values depending on the parent's attributes.

I thought that doing this in the `init` of my `BaseFormset` form would be the best way.

So here's what I do:

```
class MyBaseFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #Crispy
    ...
    super(MyBaseFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    form = self.forms[0]
    temp = Child()
    temp.x = "a"
    temp.y = "z"
    form.instance = temp
```

The first time I executed this it seems to work - but now I always get an empty/default form for my child.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? I don't get any errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you don't see the wood because of all the trees...

Just use inital value and not an object:

```
form.fields['x'].initial = self.instance.x
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have inlineformset with `extra=0`. There is decimal field which shows value as `0.0` when the page is first loaded. But when an extra row is added, the field remains `blank`. I tried your solution but getting an error `object has no attribute 'x'`. Could you please clarify? _PS_ - I assume `x` is the child model's field name (and in my case the **decimal field**).

Comment: Yes, "x" is the field name.